# Send DTMF to DAHDI channel

Tags: asterisk

I am trying to figure out a way to send DTMF commands to my ISDN modem (throught BRI Card) to enable some services it provides. For example, for call forward I need to send the DTMF *21*#. I have successfully did that with mISDN but I need to do it with DAHDI now.

So far I have managed to do this that does not work:

```
[from-internal-custom] 
exten => 4321,1,Answer
exten => 4321,n,Noop(Enable Callforward)
exten => 4321,n,Dial(DAHDI/g0/,10,M(dtmf))

[macro-dtmf]
exten => s,1,SendDTMF(*21*<number>#,,DAHDI)
```

Where number is the number I want to to do the call forward (without the <>).

If I put a ISDN Phone on the ISDN Modem I just need to dial the featurecode *21*< number ># and it works.

Is there a way to do this with DAHDI?

Answer (score 0):

There is special key for that

```
 D([called][:calling[:progress]]): Send the specified DTMF strings
    *after* the called party has answered, but before the call gets bridged.
    The  <called> DTMF string is sent to the called party, and the  <calling>
    DTMF string is sent to the calling party. Both arguments  can be used
    alone.  If <progress> is specified, its DTMF is sent immediately after
    receiving a PROGRESS message.
```

Comment: Well, I had tried both of those options (both M and D) and I get the same output:    `-- Called DAHDI/g0/
    -- DAHDI/i1/-bc is proceeding passing it to SIP/4545-000000f5
    -- Span 1: Channel 0/1 got hangup request, cause 28
    -- Hungup 'DAHDI/i1/-bc'`

Comment: That mean call not answered. I not see how you can send dtmf before call answered. You should review your dahdi settings or hire expert.